# What is the best way to get the objects from a list of keys?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to pull all the objects from my list of their keys. Is there a better way than how I'm doing it now?

```
list_of_objs = []
for obj_key in list_of_keys:
    this_obj = db.get(obj.key)
    list_of_objs.append(this_obj)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#get) db.get may accept list of keys and fetch them in a single batch, which will be much faster.

```
list_of_objects = db.get(list_of_keys)
```

Comment: Just to note here that if someone is using the ndb: `list_of_entities = ndb.get_multi(list_of_keys)`

Answer (score -1):

Not familiar with your specific application (specifically the db.get) but you may want to consider a list comprehension.

```
list_of_objs = [db.get(obj.key) for obj in list_of_keys]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list_of_objs = [db.get(key) for key in list_of_keys]
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the IN operator

```
query = db.Query()
list_of_objs = query.filter('__key__ IN', ','.join(list_of_keys))
```

this (or something similar) should do the job

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries) such queries are possible

Comment: gae-datastore is just like a dictionary afaik ... not an actual database... I think at least ...

Comment: check out the docs here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Query_structure I think it should be possible

Comment: in that case +1 ... as this is obviously preferred if the appengine thing supports it

Comment: I think this will work for my particular case, but I'm pretty sure the IN query has a limit of 30.

Comment: A query using IN with a list of length N is essentially the same as doing N separate queries with = and merging the results. i.e. not at all efficient